# div not stretching with content overlapping content

Tags: html, css

I have a div called `portfolio-container` with a list that contains 2 images inside, and a paragraph underneath each one. The problem is that he div doesn't stretch vertically, so my images and paragraphs are now overlapping my footer. I have tried setting `display: inline-block` onto the section element, container divs, list elements and images but so far nothing worked.

```css
/********************************************
PORTFOLIO
********************************************/

#portfolio {
 display: inline-block;
}

.portfolio-header {
 background-color: #0e2951;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 1em 0 0 0;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 padding: 0.1em 0.5em;
}

.portfolio-header.p {
 margin: 0;
}

.portfolio-container {
 margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
 background-color: red;
 height:100px;
 background-color: #3d7ddd;
}

.portfolio-container ul {
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
}

.portfolio-container li {
 width: 80%;
 margin: 0 auto;

}

.portfolio-container li p {
 margin: 0 0 1em 0;
 background-color: #b1caf1;
}

.portfolio-image {
 max-width: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
}


/********************************************
FOOTER
********************************************/

footer {
 border-bottom: solid 0.5em #0e2951;
 background-color: #000000;
}

.contact-icon-box {
 width: 33.333%;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 1.5em;
}
.contact-icon-link {
 width: 1em;
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #3d7ddd;
 color: #94b7ec;
 border-radius: 150px;
 font-size: 5em;
}
```

```html
<section id="porfolio">
 <div class="portfolio-header">
  <p>Some of my recent work</p>
 </div>
 <div class="portfolio-container">
  <ul>
   <li><img class="portfolio-image" src="images/ZIC-screenshot.png" alt="ZIC Homepage"><p>ZIC Homepage</p></li>
   <li><img class="portfolio-image" src="images/grafi-screenshot.jpg" alt="Javascript Interactive Graphs"><p>Interactive Js Graphs</p></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</section>

<footer>
 <div id="contact">
  <div class="contact-icon-box">
   <div class="contact-icon-link ion-social-facebook">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contact-icon-box">
   <div class="contact-icon-link ion-ios-telephone">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="contact-icon-box">
   <div class="contact-icon-link ion-email">
   </div>    
  </div>
 </div> 
</footer>
```

Comment: why would you make it a snippet, it won't display properly without the images, custom font, normalize.css and so on...

Comment: From what i understood keep the height:auto for .portfolio-container so it wouldn't overlap. Hope it helps

Comment: ugh, forgot to remove the old height: 100px code. I'm getting tired, better stop now. Write it up as an anwser, so I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the height:auto for portfolio-container

```
.portfolio-container {
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
    background-color: red;
    height:auto;
    background-color: #3d7ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the content inside you're `portfolio-container` is overlapping the footer because you have a `height` restriction on `portfolio-container`. Therefore the content has nowhere to go but down.

Either remove the `height` restriction or try using `min-height`.